# Saving enum values into a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

How does one save an enum value to a dictionary?

When I try the following

```
enum someEnum
{
    field0 = 0,
    field1 = 1,
    field2 = 2,
};

enum someEnum someEnumObject;
```

and I try to save it to a dictionary using

> [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]

```
someEnumObject, @"enum",
```

I get this

> warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'enum behaviour' to parameter of type 'id'

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the following to save it to dictionary,

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:enumValue], @"enum",
```

And you can retrieve it as,

```
enumValue = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"enum"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 13):

Better use NSNumber literals to convert an enum to an object so that it can be stored in NSDictionary:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(someEnumObject), @"enum", nil];
```

Literals provide shorthands to write stuff, this dictionary can be written like:

```
@{@"enum":@(someEnumObject)};
```

Read more about literals here:
  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 10):

An `enum` is essentially an integer and an `NSDictionary` stores objects, so you need to convert your enum to an object.  An `NSNumber` would work well for this:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someEnumObject], @"enum", nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

In modern times `@(enumValue)` is the easier approach.